# CDN JS -- cannot seem to weight it

Tags: 8, theming, cdn

I'm adding external JS in my Drupal 8 site (//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js) and I cannot seem to weight it using `hook_js_alter`. I can weight it if I throw it in a themename.libraries.yml file but then it gets rendered in every page. Ideally I want to only render the script in the home page. So this works:

```
function MYTHEME_js_alter(&$js) {
  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    $leaflet = '//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js';
    $js[$leaflet] = drupal_js_defaults();
    $js[$leaflet]['data'] = $leaflet;
    $js[$leaflet]['type'] = 'external';
    $js[$leaflet]['every_page'] = TRUE;
    $js[$leaflet]['weight'] = -100;
  }
}
```

... but it weights it last and I'd like to weight it so it loads much earlier.

if I load it via a theme.libaries.yml file, it weights it lower but it renders on every page.

```
MYTHEME-corescripts:
  version: VERSION
  js:
    //cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js: {}
    js/scripts.js: {}
```

I'm open to this method if I could somehow add context to the YAML file to indicate only fore the home page.

Comment: You could try to sort the array with https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Utility%21SortArray.php/function/SortArray%3A%3AsortByWeightElement/8 but if it would work it's just a workaround anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method below works superbly. `hook_page_alter` is the way to go and the `#attached` method. (as suggested in a comment instead of `hook_preprocess_page` I didn't know this would work for external js but it does. Pretty cool. With this method and a nested array with weight, it works as expected.

```
function MYTHEME_page_alter($cache) {

  if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
    // Render leaflet only on the home page
    $leaflet = array(
      '#attached' => array(
        'js' => array(
          '//cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.2/leaflet.js' => array(
            'group' => JS_LIBRARY,
            'weight' => -999
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($leaflet);
  }
}
```

Also of note is that we use `JS_LIBRARY` instead of `JS_THEME` here.

Comment: You should use 'hook_page_alter' instead when attaching js/css/libs.